# Does genus uniquely determine a compact connected manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Given a Smooth compact and connected 2-manifold $M$ with genus $n$. Is $M$ unique? Up to diffeomorphism, clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M$ you do not precise wether $M$ is oriented or not, $M$ is not unique.

For example the genus of the torus is $1$ and the genus of the projective plane is also $1$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)

Comment: What if $M$ was assumed to be orientable?

Comment: If $M$ is orientable, topologically, it is determined by its genus.